# Insert hidden column in asp:GridView but still available client side

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

This is simple.  All I want to do is insert a hidden column into an asp:Griview that I'll be able to access through javascript.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hide a column by setting its CssClass property, e.g:

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
</style>

...

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: All the answers were correct but I've given the tick to this was as it was more fully answered.

Answer (score 3):

Item attribute

```
ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"
```

css class

```
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. I created a hidden field inside a `TemplateField` in the `.aspx` page

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="ITEM_VAL" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ITEM_VAL") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the code behind file -

```
protected Sub gvHist_RowDataBound()
  Dim val as Integer
  Dim hiddenCol As HiddenField = e.Row.FindControl("ITEM_VAL")
  val = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenCol.Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to it the CSS property `display:none`. It will be unvisible but still present in the markup.

However this is not secure as the customer might unlock this column by using tools like FireBug which allows to override properties.

Comment: Don't worry theres nothing secure in here.  So where do I apply this style?  Item template?  This was my initial reaction also but I couldn't get it to take effect.